# ERD (Entity-relationship model) - Need an example for a prob that can not be modeled by it

Tags: erd

I got a weird H.W assignment in requirements engineering seminar .
I was digging through the entire net yet found no example for this one...
I need to find a problem from any engineering field (mechanics,medicine,chemistry,programming etc.) that the **ERD** model fails to give a complete/any answer to.

Can anyone show me some examples of a loss of information/process/entity while modeling only in **ERD** ?
maybe a point where I will need to compromise in order to continue modeling?
Or at least what are ERD's limitations ?

I need it to be an example for the limitation/disadvantage and not an example for a common mistake or bad modeling.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Well, ERD only deals with static aspects of the problem (i.e. the structure of the data that needs to be manipulated). All the information about the dynamic aspects of the problem will be lost if you only model using ERD

Comment: Could you please give me an example for such an aspect?
it seems that I am missing something in the definition of dynamic
lets say that I take an auto pilot as problem I want to model
I can find the states of the system and declare the sensors of the plane and entities
wont it make the model process possible?.. 
I have seen a lot of examples for modeling on the net but none of them shown what exactly do I loose